# Transposing a sql query with subselects and counts

Tags: sql, count, subquery, amazon-athena, unpivot

I'm needing to transpose the results of this query (the result is shown in image) to plot a histogram from the result.
Shortly is take the line of index 1 and set this as column and make main_objective, new_milestone, main_objective, main_milestone, main_kr as lines.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2nn0.png

```sql
SELECT A.main_objective,
         A.new_milestone,
         A.main_objective,
         A.main_milestone,
         A.main_kr FROM
    (SELECT 
        (SELECT count(label)
        FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
        WHERE key IN ('newarea_option_clicked')
                AND label LIKE '%option.[object_object],_objective%'
        GROUP BY  label
        ORDER BY  count(*) desc) AS new_objective, 
            (SELECT count(label)
            FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
            WHERE key IN ('newarea_option_clicked')
                    AND label LIKE '%option.[object_object],_milestones%'
            GROUP BY  label
            ORDER BY  count(*) desc) AS new_milestone, 
                (SELECT count(label)
                FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
                WHERE key IN ('okrboard_newobjective_clicked')
                GROUP BY  label
                ORDER BY  count(*) desc) AS main_objective, 
                    (SELECT count(label)
                    FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
                    WHERE key IN ('milestoneboard_newmilestone_clicked')) AS main_milestone, 
                        (SELECT count(label)FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
                        WHERE label LIKE '%+_new_key_result%') AS main_kr )A `
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach probably is to `union all` your existing subqueries:

```
    SELECT 'new_objective' metric, count(label) value
    FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
    WHERE key = 'newarea_option_clicked' AND label LIKE '%option.[object_object],_objective%'
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'new_milestone', count(label)
    FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
    WHERE key = 'newarea_option_clicked' AND label LIKE '%option.[object_object],_milestones%'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'main_objective', count(label)
    FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
    WHERE key = 'okrboard_newobjective_clicked'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'main_milestone', count(label)
    FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
    WHERE key = 'milestoneboard_newmilestone_clicked'
UNION ALL
    SELECT 'main_kr', count(label)
    FROM "roads-fe-db"."track"
    WHERE label LIKE '%+_new_key_result%'
```

Notes:

- I don't see the point for the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses in the subqueries, while your output indicates that they return one row - I removed them
- Most of your `IN` operations can be simplified as `=`
- Properly indented code is easier to write and read!